# Assertion has been violated Pipe/ClosedVolume

Tags: simulation, volume, modelica, openmodelica

I made a model on OpenModelica, simply linking a fixed-volume source with a constant-pressure source. However, I'm getting an error and can't set it. Can you please help me, I'm new to this software?Thank you for your help, Emma

```
model TestComposant
Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.IdealGases.SingleGases.N2, V = 6e-4, nPorts = 1, p_start = 40e5, use_portsData = false) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-84, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
  inner Modelica.Fluid.System system annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-170, 150}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Sources.Boundary_pT boundary1(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.IdealGases.SingleGases.N2, nPorts = 1, p = 100000) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {82, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 180)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.IdealGases.SingleGases.N2, diameter = 8e-3, length = 351.4e-3, nParallel = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-44, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  CurvedBendModel curvedBendModel(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.IdealGases.SingleGases.N2, geometry = Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.BaseClasses.Bends.CurvedBend.Geometry(d_hyd = 8e-3, R_0 = 25.5e-3, delta = 90)) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-2, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe1(redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.IdealGases.SingleGases.N2, diameter = 8e-3, length = 166e-3, nParallel = 1) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {38, 0}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(volume.ports[1], pipe.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-74, 0}, {-54, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe.port_b, curvedBendModel.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-34, 0}, {-12, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(curvedBendModel.port_b, pipe1.port_a) annotation(
    Line(points = {{8, 0}, {28, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
  connect(pipe1.port_b, boundary1.ports[1]) annotation(
    Line(points = {{48, 0}, {72, 0}}, color = {0, 127, 255}));
end TestComposant;
```

[image: Screenshot of model]

I had tweaked the code of the existing "CurvedBend" component (because I couldn't get it to work). Which explains why it doesn't exist for you.

```
model CurvedBendModel
 extends Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.Utilities.Icons.PressureLoss.Bend_i;
  extends Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.PartialPressureLoss;
  
  parameter Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.BaseClasses.Bends.CurvedBend.Geometry geometry
    "Geometry of curved bend"
      annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-20,0},{0,20}})));

protected
  parameter Medium.AbsolutePressure dp_small(min=0)=
              Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.PressureLoss.Bend.dp_curvedOverall_DP(
               Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.PressureLoss.Bend.dp_curvedOverall_IN_con(
                   d_hyd=geometry.d_hyd,
                   delta=geometry.delta,
                   K=geometry.K,
                   R_0=geometry.R_0),
                Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.PressureLoss.Bend.dp_curvedOverall_IN_var(
                  rho=Medium.density(state_dp_small),
                  eta=Medium.dynamicViscosity(state_dp_small)),
                m_flow_small)
    "Default small pressure drop for regularization of laminar and zero flow (calculated from m_flow_small)";

equation
  if allowFlowReversal then
     m_flow =  Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.BaseClasses.Bends.CurvedBend.massFlowRate(
                dp, geometry, d_a, d_b, eta_a, eta_b, dp_small, m_flow_small);
  else
     m_flow = Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.PressureLoss.Bend.dp_curvedOverall_MFLOW(
               Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.PressureLoss.Bend.dp_curvedOverall_IN_con(
                   d_hyd=geometry.d_hyd,
                   delta=geometry.delta,
                   K=geometry.K,
                   R_0=geometry.R_0),
                Modelica.Fluid.Dissipation.PressureLoss.Bend.dp_curvedOverall_IN_var(rho=d_a, eta=eta_a), dp);
  end if;
end CurvedBendModel;
```

And the error is like:
[image: Screenshot of error message]

Comment: Please fix your code, so we can copy-paste it to try it out. The protected statement contains broken annotation, there is no class definition and CurvedBendModel is missing. What error do you get? What is it what you cannot set?

Comment: Yes excuse me, I have added additional information to my post to answer your questions.

Comment: The annotation in the first code is still broken...

Comment: From skim reading the first code: Is it intentional, that you have used two different media  models, namely `N2` and `SimpleAir`?

Comment: @Markus A. I don't understand what you mean by "the annotation is still broken". I'm sorry, I'm new to OpenModelica...

I've edited my post again, hoping that's enough. 
As for the fluid, it's indeed a mistake on my part, which generates a new error.

Comment: It seems the first model is usable now. I edited the models by replacing `Geometry` with `Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.BaseClasses.Bends.CurvedBend.Geometry`. In Dymola it starts, but a simulation time of 0.0975s, the model stops with a similar error message...

Comment: Thank you very much, but the problem is that the CurvedBend component in OpenModelica, does not work. That's why I created a new component. 
From what I understand it doesn't work because the parameters in the Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.BaseClasses.Bends.CurvedBend.Geometry, are not organized in the same order as the parameters of the function that calls it. When I run the program with your information, a new error appears...

Comment: @Markus A.
Even when I try to simulate the same model without the CurvedBend, with only 1 pipe, I get the same error...

Comment: It seems the model of the medium `Modelica.Media.IdealGases.SingleGases.N2` is only valid above 200K, which is -73.15°C. When this temperature is reached, the model stops. This temperature is reached at the port of the `volume` of the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a quite high mass flow out of the volume which results in a steep pressure drop inside the volume (deltap=30 bar in 0.1s). If a gas is relaxed, its temperature decreases: this leads to the too low temperature for the medium model and the simulation stops.

The volume is adiabatic, enable heat transfer in the assumptions tab and connect e.g. a temperature source (Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Sources.FixedTemperature) to it in order to model the heat transfer into the tank from the surroundings. The simulation runs then for 1s without problems.

There is no real error here.